# Visual Studio 2013 Profiling a Cinder project, not a single function call shows up

Tags: c++, profiling, visual-studio-2013

I recently upgraded to Visual Studio 2013, and found myself in the unusual position of suddenly needing to make use of a new aspect of VS that I've never worked with before. The profiler!

Long story short - I'm working a with a simple GUI framework I've designed, that recently had gesture support added. To my horror I found what worked more or less fine in one project, bogged down my main app quite horribly. I have a fairly good idea of what's causing it, but I'd still like confirmation - and since I will likely be working quite a bit more on the framework I'm building, it certainly doesn't help to have some profiling tools in place to remove eventual bottlenecks.

I ran the Visual studio performance wizard and was surprised to see (in the 'Call Tree' view) that the output consists of essentially nothing but calls to my TTD.exe (main application) and a bunch to ntdll.dll as well as few other DLLs I'm using.

That's fine and dandy - but I was expecting a much more granular report. As in - which of my functions were being used X percent of the time and the likes. Not a single function is mentioned anywhere...

Googling a bit, I found this particular link:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scarroll/archive/2005/04/13/407984.aspx

but I highly doubt that I need to use an additional server just to serve up my - possibly missing - symbols?

I'm a bit at a loss where to begin. Perhaps the issue is that I'm using Cinder and it does a bunch of stuff behind the scenes when starting up the app? To clarify - I'm not running my app from a std. main function. Cinder essentially provides a base framework called through a macro and then my app takes over via a number of setup(), draw() and update() calls. I'd just expect to see these littered all about.

But no... O_o

Has anyone encountered anything similar?

Regards,

Gazoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to link your executable and DLLs with debug symbols.
In Debug builds this is on by default but in Release builds it's off by default.

Project properties->Linker->Debugging->Generate Debug Info = **Yes (/DEBUG)**